# pasar esta sección de horizontal en desktop a diseño vertical en movil - steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, css3

Como podria pasar esta sección de horizontal a diseño vertical para móviles.

ya se que con media queries, pero no se como aplicarle para que funcione bien.

hasta ahora tengo es esto:

```css
/*pasos anim*/

.pasos-desc span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto 22px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4285f4;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

hr {
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  width: 30px;
}

.pasos-desc1 span::before {
  right: calc(56% + 0px);
}

.pasos-desc1 span::after {
  left: calc(56% + 0px);
}

.pasos-desc1 span::before,
.pasos-desc1 span::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(10% - -1px);
  background-color: #4285f4;
  height: 1px;
  width: 98%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pasos-desc1 span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto 22px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4385f4;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pasos-desc,
.pasos-desc1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.sec-steps {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}


/*pasos anim*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 paso-1">
      <div class="pasos-desc">
        <span>1</span>
        <h4>Paso 1</h4>
        <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 paso-2">
      <div class="pasos-desc1">
        <span class="linea">2</span>
        <h4>Paso 2</h4>
        <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 paso-3">
      <div class="pasos-desc">
        <span>3</span>
        <h4>Paso 3</h4>
        <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Otra referencia visual es esta de mercadopago ar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el ejemplo mas visual q puedo decir es (mercadopago.com.ar/como-cobrar) en la parte de 1,2 y 3 q tienen ellos q es exactamente lo que quiero aprender y q me ayuden, asi para futuro ya sabre como realizarlo ya que no le encuentro manera.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo de antemano.

La estructura que tengo no es obligatoria, solo que hasta ahora así pude lograrlo.

Answer (score -1):

La idea es que **las bolas de los *items* vayan en posición absoluta** en relación a su *item* correspondiente. Yo haría **la línea con un ::before** o un ::after del contenedor y al pasar a mobile (pantalla vertical) tendrías que mover las bolas en vez de arriba al lado y la línea del contenedor igual.
Este es el concepto. Si encuentro un ejemplo te lo paso.

Comment: Tu concepto debería ir como un comentario y no como una respuesta

Comment: gracias, porfa, asi esta el codigo con un before y after en el numero 2, solo me falta que este vertical al ser movil.